# Angular 2 - Unhandled Promise when injecting a service

Tags: angular, typescript, es6-promise

I've tried to start a project from the official tutorial and I'm having a problem injecting services in my Angular2 app. everything goes fine until I add a service. Here are the files :

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { client }  from './client/client';
import { clientService } from './client/client.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <nav>
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <h2>client n° {{client.id}}</h2>
    </nav>
    <client-detail [client]="client"></client-detail>
    `,
    providers: [clientService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
    title = "client gendarmerie";
    client: client;

    constructor(private clientService: clientService) { }

    getclient(): void {
        this.clientService.getclient().then(client_eg => this.client = client_eg);
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getclient();
    }
}
```

> service/client.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { client } from './client';
import { client_EG } from './mock-client';

@Injectable()
export class clientService {
    getclient(): Promise<client> {
        return Promise.resolve(client_EG);
    }
}
```

> client/mock-client

```
import { client } from './client';

export const client_EG: client = {
    id:parseInt('10243'),
    contact: {
        phone: parseInt('0606060606'),
        access: ["Localisation", "chat", "picture"]
    },
};
```

Without the service, everything goes fine. Here is the error I get when trying to launch the app:

```
core.umd.js:3462 EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent
- inline template:3:12 caused by: Cannot read property 'id' of undefinedErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:3462(anonymous function) @ core.umd.js:6860ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:203NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ core.umd.js:6242ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:202Zone.run @ zone.js:96(anonymous function) @ zone.js:462ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:236NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask @ core.umd.js:6233ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:235Zone.runTask @ zone.js:136drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:368ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308 core.umd.js:3464 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of initial change detection tick on view it is trying to evaluate `client.id` expression, where client value is `undefined`. Because the promise for `getclient` method haven't gets resolved yet.

You could use Elvis Operator like `client?.id` and then have `ngIf` directive to hide `client-detail` Component to `client` object gets populated

**Markup**

```
<nav>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>client n° {{client?.id}}</h2>
</nav>
<client-detail *ngIf="client" [client]="client"></client-detail>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working. Why do I have to use it ? isn't the variable already there ?

Comment: @IsmaH no it doesn't available in 1st change detection run, after promise resolve another CD runs that time it is available.

Comment: @IsmaH may I know there means? With direct data it will surely work, but not with promise